# Webpack: difference about entry between production and development environment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack

I'm reading tutorial about Webpack on this: [Github Webpack tutorial](https://github.com/AriaFallah/WebpackTutorial/tree/master/part1) In this, there is a section about config webpack for production and development.

Here is development configuration:

```
// webpack.config.dev.js
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
```

Here is production configuration:

```
// webpack.config.prod.js
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: ['./src/index'],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
```

I understand the difference in option of `devtool`. The thing I don't understand about `entry`. Why in production, `entry` is only about `src/index` but in development configuration, entry also includes `webpack-dev-server`

```
'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    './src/index'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the 2 things you should know before understanding:

1. As your linked in [Webpack the confusing part](https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpack-the-confusing-parts-58712f8fcad9), there are 3 types of entry: **String** **Array** and **Object**. As above code, that is array type. Meaning of entry array is: Webpack will merged all those javascript files in array together. This is often unnecessary because Webpack is intelligent enough to know which javascript files need to merge while processing. You often need to do this to enhance some features from different javascript files that you don't include somewhere else in your code.
2. This is "little tricky" part. You see `webpack/hot/dev-server`and `webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080` look like a web url rather than some javascript files, right? If you check your project directory, you see there are those files: `your_app_directory/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js` and `your_app_directory/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client.js`. And that is the real meaning: you are importing two javascript files from two modules `webpack-dev-server` and `webpack`.

Back again to your webpack configuration:

```
entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
    'webpack/hot/dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
```

That means we will merge three different javascript files together as point 2 I have figured out. As I explain in point 1, you will do this for enhancing some features. You include file `webpack-dev-server/client.js` for making a server for serving your code. You include file `webpack/hot/dev-server.js` for allowing your code autoloading. This is super useful when you in development mode without start/stop server each time you modify your code.

Answer (score 2):

The lines `'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080'` and `'webpack/hot/dev-server'` are configuring/defining which port to attach an active websocket to, in this case `localhost:8080`, and the `content base` which in this case is folder/path `/client`. In a production environment you would never run `webpack-dev-server` as your bundled client assets (bundle.js or similar) would be served by a server (IIS, Node, etc), that is why there are no webpack related items in `entry` of the production configuration.

The Webpack plugin in question `webpack-dev-server` is **not** required to run Webpack and compile your JS sources, it simply is a tool that can be used during the development process to watch for changes and reload changes.

Technically the `entry` array property in development could simply be the `'./src/index'`, but then it wouldn't enable the webpack-dev-server and/or it's hot module reloading. If you wanted to run webpack-dev-server without these configuration items then you'd then need to add command line arguments when starting webpack to specify the port and/or content base.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: thanks. I just read on this link https://medium.com/@rajaraodv/webpack-the-confusing-parts-58712f8fcad9 about entry array. As I understand, `entry array` means we tell webpack appends multiple files together. As in my example, I will append "src/index' to `webpack/hot/dev-server` to `webpack-dev-server`.  I don't think this understanding is true because it is nonsense.

Comment: But as I understood in above link, so can you help me point out that information is true or wrong. ?

Comment: Keep in mind everything in Webpack ends up effectively becoming a module. You could technically add any amount of files/paths in the `entry` property after the `'./src/index'` item if you needed. You are not limited to the single source entry. These Webpackk entries are is just a way that the creators of `webpack-dev-server` have you connect the dev server to the browser prior to **any** other modules (js/css/etc) from being attached. It's just a requirement of configuration and using `webpack-dev-server` in a development environment. You can remove it if you don't use webpack-dev-server.